# Converting from Couchbase document to POJO using Spring-data-couchbase

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

I need to read a couchbase document and convert it to a simple pojo class object. 
From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/), I understand that I need to define some custom converter to convert that document into POJO object as it has a (non-primitive)field of type `org.apache.commons.json.JSONObject` as shown below

```
@Document
public class MyClass{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field
    private JSONObject someJsonObj;
//getters and setters

}
```

below is the repository for this

```
@Repository
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
public interface MyClassRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<MyClass, String>{}
```

while saving the object, below code is working fine,

```
     MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
     myclass.setId(someKey);
    myclass.setSomeJsonObj(jsonObject);
    myclassRepository.save(myclass);
```

and is saving the document in below format in couchbase

```
someKey {jsonObject}
```

now during retrieval, I am using a custom read converter as shown below

```
@ReadingConverter
    public static enum CouchbaseDocumentToMyClassConverter implements Converter<CouchbaseDocument,MyClass> {
        INSTANCE;
        @Override
        public MyClass convert(CouchbaseDocument source) {
            System.out.println(source.getPayload()); //this is returning lot of unwanted data like id, exp and payload for every nested json Object 
            //logic to instantiate MyClass obj 
            return new MyClass();
            }
        }
```

If i try to map the object directly to MyClass object instead of CouchbaseDocument  in the convert, then I am getting  `org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type java.lang.Object!`. Below is the complete stacktrace

```
2019-04-25 15:01:36.584 ERROR [{}] 33024 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type java.lang.Object!] with root cause
rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.java.document.RawJsonDocument.class
    at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:118) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
```

Can someone please provide some insight on how this can be solved? I directly want to map the couchbase document to my POJO class object during retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Data, you don't need to write any custom converters, the repository itself can return a POJO:

```
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Area extends BasicEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    private String description;

    private String parentAreaId;

}
```

And then, in your repository:

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
public interface AreaRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Area, String> {

    List<Area> findByParentAreaId(String parentAreaId);
}
```

Custom converters can be defined only when the object you are storing is not a POJO, like JODA or Java 8 Date-related classes.

Comment: but since I have non-primitive type `JSONObject` in my POJO, will it still be able to map?

Comment: Why do you need a JSONObject there? it defuses the whole purpose of Spring Data.

Comment: You can map your properties directly in your entity, so you can query it via N1QL or if you really need to store a JSON with random attributes, store it as a String, so you can still use DECODE_JSON to convert it to an object and query it via N1QL also. Both of them will be better choices than storing it as a JSONObject.

Comment: Have you removed your Converter? I would guess it is the reason why it is failing.